# Опережающая проверка и dotall регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Начну с того, что прекрасно понимаю, что парсить html не стоит с помощью регулярных выражений, но в данном случае просто по-быстрому нужно было реализовать кое-что. В итоге напоролся на проблему, и теперь интересно её решение.

Исходные данные:

```
Lorem <a data-smth-id="1" href="#">ipsum dolor sit amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<a data-smth-id="2" href="#">Sed ut maximus turpis. In pulvinar pulvinar mattis.
Suspendisse dapibus</a> a orci eu suscipit.
<a id="smth_to_smw" href="#">In quis erat non nisl vehicula egestas.</a>
Etiam interdum semper cursus.
```

Есть следующее регулярное выражение: `#<a(?!.\*id="smth\_to\_smw").\*>(.\*)</a>#iU`

Этим выражением я хочу получить все элементы **a**, в которых отсутсвует id, указанный в регулярном выражении. И действительно, если содержание ссылки находится на одной строке, то всё работает как нужно. Вторую ссылку не находит по причине того, что символ точка в регулярном выражении по умолчанию равен всем символам, кроме символа переноса строки. Отсюда следует, что к регулярному выражению логично добавить флаг s (dotall), но после этого вместо ожидаемой работы регулярное выражение не находит вообще ничего. Может, кто знает, в чём проблема?

Comment: Напишите регулярку правильно. Она в тексте какая то неверная.

Comment: Спасибо. Поправил. В окне предпросмотра она как-то странно отображается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На этот случай есть такой трюк:

`[\s\S]*` - матчит все символы.

```
#<a(?!.*id="smth_to_smw").*>([\s\S]*)</a>#iU
```

На вашем тексте:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [35-55] `ipsum dolor sit amet`
MATCH 2
1.  [119-190]   `Sed ut maximus turpis. In pulvinar pulvinar mattis.
Suspendisse dapibus`
```

**[Посмотреть пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/gU0uV5/1)**

Comment: Шикарно. Вы великолепны. Я примерно о таком решении задумывался, правда не знаю, почему не попробывал сам. А не знаете, по какой причине флаг доталл так отрабатыает?

Comment: @Jeremen1, к сожалению, моих знаний недостаточно, чтобы ответить на этот вопрос.